# Compiler not starting successfully in VimTex on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, latex

Getting the following output when trying to compile in gVim using vimtex.

```
panic: no console

goroutine 1 [running]:
modernc.org/libc.newFile(0x0, 0xc000000000, 0xc0000e2000)
    D:/a/cli/cli/vendor/modernc.org/libc/libc_windows.go:227 +0x185
modernc.org/libc.init()
    D:/a/cli/cli/vendor/modernc.org/libc/libc.go:53 +0x22a5
```

The latex file is the most basic template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 This is a test.
\end{document}
```

saved under test.tex

Here is the .vimrc.

```
set encoding=utf-8   

call plug#begin()
" On-demand loading
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
call plug#end()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

For information: vimtex is installed (syntax does highlight), Latex is installed and the file compiles when I type

```
pdflatex .\test.tex
```

in the PowerShell.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Was not sure about doing that, ok, thanks.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/2258